# How I can fill my ListView in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I new in the Android Programming and I want built a digital Schoolplan. For this I use a few Activities. I want create a plan and list them in a ListView that the User can click in the ListView on this Control and see all Homeworks and so.

Here is my Idea:

[image]

I build a Activity for the CreateMain:

```
 public void createPlan(View view)
    {
        String PlanName;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListenActivity.class);

        EditText planName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        PlanName = planName.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra(ListViewMessage, PlanName); 

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

And a Activity for show the create data in a ListView

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ListenActivity extends ListActivity {

    private CommentsDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        // elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Comment comment = null;

          String[] comments = new String[] { "t1", "t2", "t3" };

          comment = datasource.createComment(comments[1]); 

          adapter.add(comment);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_list, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how I can use the data from the activity before for this activity in my ListView. I want to use a SQLite database but it don't work :(

Comment: Let me see if I understand you well. You want to pass data through your activities with SQLite?

Comment: yes I want that I can add a ListView Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to pass data through Activities. Since you stored your information in a `Bundle` I will answer following that same logic.

If you didn't notice, you stored your information in the **Intent's Extra Bundle** in your `createPlan` method. After that, you started that `Intent`.

According to the official documentation:
"*...extras -- This is a Bundle of any additional information. This can be used to provide extended information to the component. For example, if we have a action to send an e-mail message, we could also include extra pieces of data here to supply a subject, body, etc...*"

So, to get that information you might use `getIntent().getExtras()` inside your `ListenActivity` to take back your `Bundle` and then you pass the key you used to store the plan's name using `getIntent().getExtras().getString(your_key)`.

For example:

```
public class ListenActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //...your stuff

   String planName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ListViewMessage);

   //...your stuff
}
```

}

I don't recommend the use of SQLite to store small amount of data. If you really want to use it, there are very nice examples [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial).